# How do I use the node.js function in a normal frontend javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, export, puppeteer

I have made a node.js puppeteer page which outputs covid cases in Canada. I want to take that function and use it in a javascript frontend website that shows information on Canada's covid cases. How do I take this function and export it to a javascript page so I can use it there. This is my code so far:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer")
let dataExplained = {}
async function getCovidCases(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    const url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries"
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'})
    const results = await page.$$eval(".even", navBars => {
        return navBars.map(navBar => {
          const anchors = Array.from(navBar.getElementsByTagName('td'));
          return anchors.map(anchor => anchor.innerText);
        });
      })
      browser.close()
      dataExplained.country = results[15][1]
      dataExplained.totalCases = results[15][2]
      dataExplained.newCases    = results[15][3]
      dataExplained.totalDeaths    = results[15][4]
      dataExplained.newDeaths    = results[15][5]
      dataExplained.totalRecovered    = results[15][6]
      dataExplained.activeCases    = results[15][7]
      dataExplained.critical    = results[15][8]
      dataExplained.totalCasesPerMillion    = results[15][9]
      dataExplained.deathsPerMillion    = results[15][10]
      dataExplained.totalTests    = results[15][11]
      dataExplained.totalTestsPerMillion    = results[15][12]
      dataExplained.population = results[15][13]
      return dataExplained
}
let covid = getCovidCases()
covid.then((result) => console.log(result))
```

**Please Help.
Thank You!**

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can't export a function to the front end, Puppeteer runs on the server. You need to expose the result using an Express route endpoint or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

This node.js code is only going to run on your server.  So, you have to somehow run it on your server and communicate the results back to the front-end.  There are several ways to do that:

1. **Ajax call that returns JSON.**  From the front-end, you can make an Ajax call to the back-end, the back-end fetches the results that match the request and returns them back to the front-end as a JSON response.  The front-end parses that JSON into a Javascript object and then inserts that data into the current web page.
2. **Build dynamic HTML on the server.** The user requests a web page from your server.  Your server builds that web page dynamically by fetching the required data and then converting the data into displayable HTML and returning a pre-built web page to the browser which then displays the web page (with the requested data embedded into it).  You can either build this web page manually with server-side code or you can use a  template engine for incorporating the dynamic data into the web page.

And, there are variations of this where the front-end requests JSON from the server, then uses a front-end template engine to construct dynamic content which it inserts into the current page.